# How can I find all the self defined variables and functions to unset?

Tags: bash, shell, variable

In a bash shell process, I define some variables and functions here and there. So they are hard to track. How can I find all the self defined variables and functions to unset? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean after all the shell initialization files have loaded? At what point do you consider it "you" versus /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc?

Comment: I was interested in after. Now I am also interested in before, i.e. unset those defined in the initialization files.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to track which variables and functions you create.  Instead, run the code in a subshell.  When the subshell completes, all variables and functions defined within the subshell disappear.

In bash, one way to explicitly put commands in a subshell is to place the commands inside parens: `(...)`.  For example, let's define two variables and a function within a subshell and execute the function:

```
$ ( a=1; b=2; fn() { echo "a=$a b=$b"; }; fn )
a=1 b=2
```

After the subshell completes, all are erased:

```
$ fn
bash: fn: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: compare an "empty" environment with your current one

```
env -i bash set > baseline
set > now
diff baseline now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use compgen -v to list all variables defined within bash and compgen -A function to list all the functions

Comment: That lists all variables, not just the variables defined in a particular script.