# Opposite of the `source` command

Tags: bash, shell-script, source

I use the `source` command in my bash script in order to read/print the variables values

```
more linuxmachines_mount_point.txt

export linuxmachine01="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
export linuxmachine02="sde sdd sdb sdf sdc"
export linuxmachine03="sdb sdd sdc sde sdf"
export linuxmachine06="sdb sde sdf sdd"

source  linuxmachines_mount_point.txt

echo $linuxmachine01
sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg
```

What is the opposite of `source` in order to unset the variables?

Expected results

```
echo $linuxmachine01

< no output >
```

Comment: It is not `source` that is setting the variables in your environment, but the `export` statements in the file which you `source`.  So the opposite of `source` could be `source`, if you `source` a different file which `unset`s all the same variables.

Comment: yael, don't use exports, just use name="val". Export is for script-to-binaries variables (the environment).

Comment: i must to use export , without export variable will not get the value try it on your system ( and I must read from the file )

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382618/117549

Comment: This is impossible. The concept you are looking for is called *Reversible Computing*. Programming languages need to be *specifically* designed with some severe restrictions in order to be reversible. Bash is not one of those programming languages.

Comment: @yael, that's untrue (and you obviously never ran the test you're telling ctrl-d to do); you absolutely do not need the `export`s. All `export` does is copy the values into the environment -- but they're present as shell variables whether or not they're defined as environment variables as well. Moreover, defining unnecessary environment variables shortens your maximum command line length, as they're stored in the same (limited!) per-process space.

Comment: @yael, ...moreover, if you *did* have a use case where you needed to define all the variables in the environment, you still don't need `export`s -- you could just run `set -a` (auto-exporting all newly-defined variables) before `source`ing the script, and `set +a` afterwards to turn that off.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Using a subshell (Recommended)

Run the source command in a subshell:

```
(
source linuxmachines_mount_point.txt
cmd1 $linuxmachine02
other_commands_using_variables
etc
)
echo $linuxmachine01  # Will return nothing
```

Subshells are defined by parens: `(...)`.  Any shell variables set within the subshell are forgotten when the subshell ends.

#### Using unset

This unsets any variable exported by `linuxmachines_mount_point.txt`:

```
unset $(awk -F'[ =]+' '/^export/{print $2}' linuxmachines_mount_point.txt)
```

- `-F'[ =]+'` tells awk to use any combination of spaces and equal signs as the field separator.
- `/^export/{print $2}`

  This tells awk to select lines that begin with `export` and then print the second field.
- `unset $(...)`

  This runs the command inside `$(...)`, captures its stdout, and unsets any variables named by its output.

Comment: why not to use this - for i in ` awk '{print$2}' file | awk -F"=" '{print$1}' `; do unset $i; done ? ( more simple for unset )

Comment: @yael That uses an extra process and a loop when neither are needed.  Opinions may vary but I don't see that as simpler.  Also and potentially dangerous, it assumes that every line in `file` is an export statement.

Comment: @yael Also, unsetting variables and undoing other code side-effects is exactly what subshells are for.  They do it simply and reliably.  Unless there is some special reason otherwise, subshells are what you should be using.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot un`source` the script.

What you can do is to store all exported variables in a temporary file, compare it with variables after the script is sourced, and then removed overflow with `unset`, e.g.:

```
export > temp_file
source myscript

#... do some stuff

unset "$(comm -3 <(sort temp_file) <(export | sort) | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $3}' | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

Comment: why not to use this - for i in ` awk '{print$2}' file | awk -F"=" '{print$1}' `; do unset $i; done ? ( more simple  for unset )

Comment: @yael it will work only if script contains only `export`s.

Comment: what you mean "export s" , my file include linuxmachine01="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg" and so on , and when I use the awk loop its unset the variable without problems

Comment: @yael I don't know how exactly your file looks like, so I gave some general answer, for example what if the script contains a comment at the top saying "# Here are some variable to export with mount points.".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unset` command to "forget" variables.

Comment: file could be with diff machines , so how to unset the second variables in the file?

Comment: unset variablename  will forget it  (you can find it explained in bash/sh/ksh/zsh man page) demo of it : https://pastebin.com/MGQyTZEA

Comment: yes but because variables could be diff , bash script need to do it by read the variable from the file and unset them  , it cant be static because variable are unknown

Comment: then grep yours export lines (cut) to list variables from the file to be unset     export linuxmachine06="sdb sde sdf sdd"  then you get linuxmachine06 as a name to unset  example : https://pastebin.com/M9eCtLc7 as you see the unset command here doen't know the variable name it is known only at end

Comment: ok I will use this syntax in order to unset - for i in `  awk '{print$2}'  file | awk -F"=" '{print$1}' `; do unset $i; done

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to have the output you expect (nothing) is to re-declare the variable as empty:

```
$ export linuxmachine01="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
$ echo "$linuxmachine01"
sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg

$ linuxmachine01=""
$ echo "$linuxmachine01"
$
```

Of course the variable is still defined (and exported), empty but defined:

```
$ declare -p linuxmachine01
declare -x linuxmachine01=""
```

To correctly remove the variable from both the environment and the running shell you should use unset (the recommended way):

```
$ unset linuxmachine01
$ declare -p linuxmachine01
bash: declare: linuxmachine01: not found
$ echo "$linuxmachine01"
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to modify your script so it also defines a command to undo the effect of the script:

```
export linuxmachine01="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
export linuxmachine02="sde sdd sdb sdf sdc"
export linuxmachine03="sdb sdd sdc sde sdf"
export linuxmachine06="sdb sde sdf sdd"
alias linuxmachines_mount_point='for v in linuxmachine01 linuxmachine02 linuxmachine03 linuxmachine04; do unset $v; done; unalias linuxmachines_mount_point'
```

Comment: Why an alias rather than a function? Note that aliases are disabled in noninteractive shells by default, so out-of-the-box, this won't work in a script.

Comment: ...actually, this would be even easier if we defined *just one* variable, and thus had only one to unset: `declare -A linuxmachines=( [01]="sdb sdc sdf" [02]="sde sdd sdb" [03]="whatever" )`, then it's just `unset linuxmachines` to revert.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: both alias and function are fine for this purpose. The reason I don't suggest putting everything into one variable is that defining an undo command is much more generic. You can undefine not just variables but also functions, aliases, system settings, terminal settings, etc. It provides a better abstraction as you don't have to care about the exact content of the undo command.

Comment: I believe my point above is that aliases *are not* fine for the purpose, if "the purpose" includes noninteractive use (ie. invocation from scripts).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your linuxmachines_mount_point.txt like this

```
test "$linuxmachine01" && unset -v linuxmachine01 || linuxmachine01="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
```

When you need your variables

```
source linuxmachines_mount_point.txt
```

When you want to remove the variables

```
source linuxmachines_mount_point.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `source` command to activate a `VirtualEnvironment`, you can exit it using the command `deactivate`.